# MYSQL CASE/IF over a value selected with SELECT

Tags: mysql

I'd like to run a CASE statement or IF on the COUNT_A returned by the select query below and set the value of a variable A_VAL.

```
SELECT A_DATE, COUNT(A_INS_NAM) AS COUNT_A
FROM TABLE1
WHERE A_INS_NAM IN
(
    SELECT A_INS_NAM FROM IWD
    WHERE I_ID IN
    (
        SELECT IM_ID FROM TIM WHERE IM_ID = (
            SELECT T_ID FROM TWS WHERE TN = 'abced')
    )
) AND A_DATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2015-05-01' AND A_INS_NAM NOT LIKE '%pk%'
```

I'd like the output to have 2 columns namely A_DATE, A_VAL. The value of A_VAL gets set based on

```
If COUNT_A  = 10, then  A_VAL = 1
If COUNT_A  = 20, then  A_VAL = 2
If COUNT_A  between 30 & 50, then  A_VAL =  3
If COUNT_A  > 50, then  A_VAL = 5
```

Could I get someone's help please?

Comment: You really need to explain in basic English what your query is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use joins instead of sub queries for better performance something like below, also you are using an aggregate function without providing grouping criteria so it will result as a single row for this i have added `GROUP BY  t.A_DATE` in below query

```
SELECT 
  t.A_DATE,
  CASE
   WHEN COUNT(t.A_INS_NAM) = 10 THEN   1
   WHEN COUNT(t.A_INS_NAM) = 20 THEN   2
   WHEN COUNT(t.A_INS_NAM) BETWEEN 30 AND 50 THEN  3
   WHEN COUNT(t.A_INS_NAM)  > 50 THEN  5
   ELSE 'some value' 
  END AS A_VAL
FROM
  TABLE1 t
  JOIN IWD t1 ON(t.A_INS_NAM = t1.A_INS_NAM)
  JOIN TIM t2 ON(t1.IWD = t2.IM_ID)
  JOIN TWS t3 ON(t2.IM_ID = t3.T_ID )
WHERE t3.TN = 'abced'
  AND t.A_DATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2015-05-01' 
  AND t.A_INS_NAM NOT LIKE '%pk%' 
GROUP BY  t.A_DATE
```

Comment: Thank you very much Khalid. This works. Appreciate your help. Thank you again.

Comment: Hello Khalid/All - If I'd like the total (SUM()) of A_VAL as the output, how can I do that? Any help please?

Comment: @user3124689 you can ask a new question with all the details

Comment: Thank you Khalid. the question is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30868538/mysql-sum-over-case-statement