# MySQL SUM over CASE statement

Tags: mysql

Could someone please help me get the SUM of A_VAL in the below SQL

```
SELECT 
  CASE
   WHEN COUNT(t.A_INS_NAM) = 10 THEN   1
   WHEN COUNT(t.A_INS_NAM) = 20 THEN   2
   WHEN COUNT(t.A_INS_NAM) BETWEEN 30 AND 50 THEN  3
   WHEN COUNT(t.A_INS_NAM)  > 50 THEN  5
   ELSE 'some value' 
  END AS A_VAL
FROM
  TABLE1 t
  JOIN IWD t1 ON(t.A_INS_NAM = t1.A_INS_NAM)
  JOIN TIM t2 ON(t1.IWD = t2.IM_ID)
  JOIN TWS t3 ON(t2.IM_ID = t3.T_ID )
WHERE t3.TN = 'abced'
  AND t.A_DATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2015-05-01' 
  AND t.A_INS_NAM NOT LIKE '%pk%'
```

Comment: What do you mean "sum of a_val"?  THis query returns one row with an `A_VAL` value.  What do you want the sum of?  The question does not make sense.  Sample data and desired results are very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub select to calculate sum, note you are using an aggregate function without group by it will result as a single row

```
SELECT SUM(A_VAL)
FROM (
    SELECT 
      CASE
       WHEN COUNT(t.A_INS_NAM) = 10 THEN   1
       WHEN COUNT(t.A_INS_NAM) = 20 THEN   2
       WHEN COUNT(t.A_INS_NAM) BETWEEN 30 AND 50 THEN  3
       WHEN COUNT(t.A_INS_NAM)  > 50 THEN  5
       ELSE 'some value' 
      END AS A_VAL
    FROM
      TABLE1 t
      JOIN IWD t1 ON(t.A_INS_NAM = t1.A_INS_NAM)
      JOIN TIM t2 ON(t1.IWD = t2.IM_ID)
      JOIN TWS t3 ON(t2.IM_ID = t3.T_ID )
    WHERE t3.TN = 'abced'
      AND t.A_DATE BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2015-05-01' 
      AND t.A_INS_NAM NOT LIKE '%pk%'
) a
```

Comment: Thank you very much Khalid. I added the group by date & summed up the column. Excellent. Thank you heaps again.

Comment: @user3124689 . . . I don't see how this would help you since it would return the same value as the subquery (unless the `else` clause really does return a non-numeric value).

Comment: Hello Gordon - Without the SUM column, I would get data as follows 
DATE | A_VAL <br>
01-01-2015 | 12 <br>
01-01-2015 | 12 <br>

with SUM, i get the total 36. Let me know if this isn't clear.